# What is the purpose of this line of code in wp_trim_excerpt?

Tags: core

Can someone please explain what the purpose of this code is:

```
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
```

I'm referring to a line of code inside [wp_trim_excerpt()](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_trim_excerpt/), but I've seen something very similar in some other wp functions as well.

On the surface, I would say it's not doing anything at all, but I have to give the wordpress developers more credit than that, so I'm sure there's a reason for this.  I've looked into the php manual for [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to see if there is some special return value but everything is as I would expect.

Is this some sort of ninja data validation technique?

Comment: Sorry, my fault with encoding in QueryPosts. :( Added to bugs list. If not sure please double check in linked repositories.

Comment: Definitely not a ninja data validation technique.

Comment: @Rarst, thanks Rarst.  I love QueryPosts :)  When are those classes coming?

Comment: @Evan having capacity to work on new parser for those classes is like a light in the end tunnel for me. But it's a long tunnel so far...

Comment: Bugfix live (might take bit more time to wash out of cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement string contains a HTML entity which when displayed on a browser, looks like the needle string. It's converting > to a HTML entity.

Reference: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2119

Comment: To clarify, since this answer confused me momentarily - it looks like queryposts.com is decoding the HTML entity. Core's sourcecode will show that it turns `]]>` into `]]&gt;`

Comment: @BrianFegter - I see now. Even still, what is the purpose of that replace? It seems like the only thing it would match would be a closing CDATA tag?  Shouldn't encoding like this be done before saving rather than right before displaying?

Comment: @EvanMattson CDATA tag closing